# Why Oracle parallel streams tutorial uses new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr))?

Tags: java, java-8

The [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) on parallel streams creates an `ArrayList` instance from the output of `Arrays.asList` even though it is used as a source of a stream and never appended to.

Sample code from the tutorial:

```
Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
List<Integer> listOfIntegers =
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intArray));

System.out.println("listOfIntegers:");
listOfIntegers
    .stream()
    .forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
System.out.println("");
```

Why not just keep the `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` (the output type of `Arrays.asList`)? Does it have some weird properties in a parallel streams?

Comment: In this case there's no point for it. Could even use `Arrays.stream(intArray)`.

Comment: Agree. This is just a snippet. In the other parts of the tutorial they do operate on the `List` (sort it, use to create multiple streams).

Comment: You can post a bug/RFE for the tutorials at either http://bugreport.java.com/ or send a suggestion for improvement to mailto:javasedocs_us@oracle.com.  If you post a bug, use category docs/tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

In this code fragment, there is no need for it. I guess, the code was the result of the writers *initial intention* to create an `ArrayList` and fill it with some predefined values.

So there might have been the following mindset:

```
Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer i: intArray) listOfIntegers.add(i);
```

or

```
Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(listOfIntegers, intArray);
```

Using this starting point, `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intArray))` is an improvement in both, brevity and efficiency as its source code is shorter and it allows the `ArrayList` to size its internal array exactly to the number of contained elements.

However, it’s easy to overlook that the `ArrayList` is obsolete then. As a side note, you can also write `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)`, in other words, it’s also easy to overlook that even the manual array creation is not necessary.

This is not an unusual situation. I encountered code which makes sense given its history but not for an unbiased reader more than occasional. That’s why it is strongly recommended to let your code be reviewed by someone, who doesn’t know its history, from time to time.

Regarding parallel processing, both and the result of `Arrays.asList` have the property of being backed by an array, allowing random access, and producing ordered streams which support splitting. The `ArrayList`’s parallel processing might be slightly less efficient due to checks for concurrent modifications which are demonstrated by the [Interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#interference) example in that tutorial. This example indeed requires an `ArrayList` as it will add elements to it. As the array wrapper list does not support adding, that example wouldn’t work with it and it doesn’t need such checks.

Answer (score -3):

Later on in the code sample `Collections.sort(listOfIntegers, reversed);` is used.

Since `Arrays.asList()` produces an immutable `List` instance, that line would fail.

Comment: Not exactly immutable: you can use `set`, but you cannot `add` to it.

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns a `List` with a fixed size but it's perfectly fine to sort it. http://ideone.com/y8cJvT